# Pull data from multiple closed workbooks and sheets in excel

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, range

I want to pull data from multiple workbooks and worksheets that are closed.
I'm able to extract the data by using the below formula:

```
=INDEX('C:\Users\Shubham\Downloads\Ex_Files_Excel_Macros_and_VBA_for_Beginners\Ex_Files_Excel_Macros_and_VBA_for_Beginners\Exercise Files\[03_01 Undo.xlsx]Attendance'!C:C, 6)
```

but I want to provide the path in a cell using CONCATENATE function let's say in E5 so that value in E5 comes like below:

```
'C:\Users\Shubham\Downloads\Ex_Files_Excel_Macros_and_VBA_for_Beginners\Ex_Files_Excel_Macros_and_VBA_for_Beginners\Exercise Files\[03_01 Undo.xlsx]Attendance'!C:C
```

So I want to use the formula like:

```
= INDEX(E5, 6)
```

where E5 has the path and range defined but this doesn't take the value in E5 as table array.

I can't use the indirect formula since it doesn't work with closed workbooks. I have tried to understand the VBA code but doesn't work out.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out to resolve this issue since I have to extract data from multiple workbooks and multiple sheets and have to use dynamic reference to path and range.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, wanting to extract data from multiple workbooks with a volatile worksheet address.  Indirect and Concatenate worked, but only when source files were open.  There is no function which would work with closed files.
A macro was the solution, which I found here;
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-to-pull-data-from-dynamically-named-closed-workbooks.984156/

My solution uses a list of the source file name components with a volatile date component (date is the only variable in the source file names) and a volatile worksheet component (I need to take data for a person, where each person's name is the name of a worksheet in each file).
That list looks like this;[List of File Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4AgZ.png)

I and K (Name) are volatile.  These are modified in my list by having these cells reference separate input cells to simplify a query.  Enter the name and the latest payroll date you want to query.  It looks back a set number of cycles.

The formula to get the data I want is `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(H4,I4,J4,K4,L4)),"S")`
How many times does `S` appear in range `D63:U63` in tab Moe for each file.

The macro solution uses the Date information in column I to open all the source files as follows  (I have added comments to hopefully make it clearer what each step does);

```vb
Public Sub Macro_Name()

'  Opens Timesheets files to allow "Indirect" formula to obtain data

Dim r As Long
'  I don't know what this does, but it is necessary

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'  Stops screen updating to speed up operation

Calculate
'  Calculates to clear any previous data in the file.  File is set to manual calculation.

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    For r = 4 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    '  Starting at row 4, uses data in column I in the command below until the end of the data.  You can't have any other data in column I.       

        Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\Payroll\Weekly Timesheets " & .Cells(r, "I") & ".xlsm"
        '  Opens each file called   Weekly Timesheets [date].xlsm
    Next
    
Windows("[The name of your working file].xlsm").Activate
Calculate
Range("B2").Select
'  This calculates your working file and goes to a convenient "home" cell

End With

Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
Next
'  This sub routine closes all open Excel files EXCEPT your working file.  Best not to have other files open as it is set NOT to save.

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I found this page to set the file for manual calculation, which I preferred.
https://excel.tips.net/T001988_Forcing_Manual_Calculation_For_a_Workbook.html

I'm not sure if this solution is efficient, and it is not perhaps as elegant as I would like, but it has worked for me.  I hope it helps.

Big shoutout to John_w at MrExcel.com who provided the core code above.  I just fiddled a few things so it worked for me.